# How do I cover Cellstrainers?

Tags: cell-biology, microbiology, lab-techniques, cell-culture, flow-cytometry

I‘m doing some experiments for my bachelors thesis and I‘m using some Cell strainers by Roth for it ([https://www.carlroth.com/com/en/accessories/cell-strainer-easystrainer™/p/cly9.1](https://www.carlroth.com/com/en/accessories/cell-strainer-easystrainer%E2%84%A2/p/cly9.1)). My problem is that the setup is supposed to stay in an incubator at 37 °C for up to 3 weeks and it needs to be covered the entire time. Sadly I didn‘t find a proper way to cover the cell strainers which sit on top of a regular 50 mL Falcon tube. Does anyone of you have an idea or can speak from experience?

P.S.: Parafilm doesn‘t work since it gets sticky at those temperatures.

Comment: What about just setting the cap of the 50 mL tube on top of the strainer? It'll still allow some airflow, but should protect against contamination settling into it.

Comment: @MattDMo I‘m affraid the pbs solution inside the Falcon tube would evaporate. Air flow isn’t important to me since I just misuse the cellstrainer as a sample holder for a nanocomposite hydrogel I synthesized. But you just gave me an idea that might just work out. Thanks a lot!!